# Align two rows in table

Tags: tables, cv

I am building a cv using longtable.  I would like to have the first word of the "second line"  aligned with the first word of the first line in the list with bullet points.

Here is an example:

```
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Change the font size of your document - 10pt, 12.1pt, etc.
\documentclass[letterpaper,8pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, xltabular}

\usepackage{scrextend}

\usepackage{marvosym}


\usepackage[centering, left=2cm, bottom=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[centering,includeheadfoot,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%% Distances

% width of the table
\newcommand\x{11cm}  % width

% distance line-bold
\newcommand\dista{0.2cm}

% distance bold-text
\newcommand\distb{0.01cm}

% distance text-bold/line
\newcommand\distc{0.4cm}


\begin{document}


\vspace{-0.2cm}

\begin{longtable}{@{} >{}l p{\x} @{}}
    \hline \noalign{\vskip \dista}
    \Large{\textbf{Academic Experience}}  & 
    \textbf{Teaching Assistantship} \\[\distb]
    \small{Spring 2020}                                                    
    &
    \tabitem Open Economy Macroeconomics, IDEA Ph.D. program, UAB. Mario Rossi Vella\\
    \small{Fall 2018 and Fall 2019}                                                            
    &
    Macroeconomics I, IDEA Ph.D. program, UAB. Prof. Mario Rossi Vella \\
    \small{Fall 2019}
    &
    \tabitem Econometric I with R (in Spanish), undergraduate, UAB. Mario Rosahahahsi Vellalalal.\\
    \small{Fall 2018}
    &
    \tabitem Econometrics I with GRETL (in Spanish), undergraduate, UAB. Lauraahaha Pinyol.\\       
    \small{Spring 2018}
    &
    \tabitem Statistics I with GRETL (in Spanish), undergraduate, UAB.\\ \addlinespace[\distc]                                                                                                                                     
\end{longtable}




\end{document}
```

Comment: There are specific classes that address cv writing, like `moderncv`,`europecv`. You can either use them, or take inspiration from their class file to address your needs in your own code.
Indeed, using `longtable` may be a good starting point, but has also its limits on the long run. Most notably page breaking, when you end up with long descriptions for a single entry of the cv (with which I am dealing right now).

Comment: See similar question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530971/multirow-spacing/530996#530996. You may get an idea how to solve your problem. However, I would rather stick with @AlessandroCuttin comment.

Comment: Thanks. @Zarco, I asked that question yesterday :-). I have a new problem now and that answer does not help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it, using a supplementary column for the bullets. I added some improvements to the layout and some code simplifications:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,8pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\let\tabitem\textbullet
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, xltabular}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\usepackage{marvosym}

\usepackage[centering, left=2cm, vmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%% Distances

% width of the table
\newcommand\x{11cm} % width

% distance line-bold
\newcommand\dista{0.2cm}

% distance bold-text
\newcommand\distb{0.01cm}

% distance text-bold/line
\newcommand\distc{0.4cm}

\begin{document}

\vspace{-0.2cm}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{>{\small}ll@{\hskip\labelsep} p{\x} @{}}
    \hline \noalign{\vskip \dista}
    \Large{\textbf{Academic Experience}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Teaching Assistantship}} \\\addlinespace[1ex]
    Spring 2020
    & \tabitem & Open Economy Macroeconomics, IDEA Ph.D. program, UAB. Mario Rossi Vella\\
    Fall 2018 and Fall 2019
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Macroeconomics I, IDEA Ph.D. program, UAB. Prof. Mario Rossi Vella} \\
    Fall 2019
    & \tabitem & Econometric I with R (in Spanish), undergraduate, UAB. Mario Rosahahahsi Vellalalal.\\
    Fall 2018
    & \tabitem & Econometrics I with GRETL (in Spanish), undergraduate, UAB. Lauraahaha Pinyol.\\
    Spring 2018
    & \tabitem & Statistics I with GRETL (in Spanish), undergraduate, UAB.\\ \addlinespace[\distc]

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]